# Формула расчета урона

Tags: разработка-игр

Сложилась такая проблема, что у меня не получаеться сделать формулу подсчета урона. Учитывая некоторые факторы двух персонажей (которые с друг другому бьются). Нужно учитывать броню врага, мой урон, множитель урона и разность уровней. Важно, чтобы если разность уровней большая, то шанс попадания снижается в коэффициенте разности.

Comment: Так у вас вопрос по реализации формулы на C# или у вас вопрос по самой формуле, которую вы не знаете как посчитать по вашим факторам (и тогда при чём тут C#)?

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что вопрос пока совсем абстрактный. Какую формулу вы пытались сделать и что в ней не устраивает?

Comment: @MBo для тех, кто в танке, я выделяю контекст из вопроса: "не получаеться сделать формулу подсчета урона" на вопрос: "Какую формулу вы пытались сделать и что в ней не устраивает?".

Comment: @CrazyElf ошибок тут нет! Все верно, на C# желательно пример реализовать.

Comment: @CrazyElf если не знаете ответа, на что я в большей степени наклонен, то не вставляйте свое не нужное Я.

Comment: @Alexey Хорошо, я просто минус вашему вопросу за ваш стиль общения поставлю, да и всё )  Вам пытаются помочь, пытаясь почётче выяснить суть вопроса, если вам это не надо, то и ладно. А по сути вам нужно просто найти типовую какую-то формулу игровой механики что там на что умножать вычитать и делить. Можете начать откуда-то отсюда: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129322/160572 В чём сложность перевода формулы на C# мне лично непонятно, там будет элементарная арифметика.

Comment: По поводу организации кода, почитайте вот это: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/ (и остальные части)

Comment: @CrazyElf Да как-то пох на ваши минусы эти, по поводу вас и этого сайта все смеются с мемов) Так что спорить с клоунами такое себе)

Comment: @Alexey И тем не менее это видимо самый популярный сайт для программистов. Но не для всего на свете, конечно. Ссылку на тот подраздел, где обсуждают именно геймдев, я выше привёл, лучше искать и спрашивать такое именно там.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я самостоятельно высчитал формулу расчета урона, с учетом разницы уровня, который отражает одну единицу разницы в 5% дополнительного урона.
Для расчета урона, с учетом атаки, защиты врага и разности уровней, можно использовать следующую формулу:

```
Урон = (Атака - Защита) * (1 + 0.05 * Разность уровней)
```

Где:

- Атака - это сила атаки вашего персонажа.
- Защита - это защита врага.
- Разность уровней - это разница между уровнем вашего персонажа и
  уровнем врага.

Эта формула учитывает, что урон увеличивается на 5% за каждый уровень разницы между уровнями вашего персонажа и врага.

Обратите внимание, что данная формула может вернуть отрицательные значения.

Comment: Поскольку в данном вами и принятом вами же ответе ничего нет ни про `C#` ни про `Unity3d`, я эти метки с вопроса убрал.